# Salesforce Streaming API Handshake denied

Tags: api, salesforce, streaming, handshake, cometd

I am using streaming api and cometD in community.
It works fine for authorized users but still doesnt work for Guest user. For example, in anonymous window. And every time i receve Handshake denied w/ error '401::Authentication invalid'.
What's the problem exactly? But if i log in anonymous window to org then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will be using `{!$Api.Session_ID}` which will return `null` in the case of Salesforce Guest user.

**Because Guest User doesn't have a session id to access salesforce streaming API.**

You need to authenticate as a user in order to stream and subscribe to events for **cometD**.

If you want to stream events for guest users:

- you have to spend a platform license by creating a dedicated user for it.
- save the creds of a user in custom settings
- generate an access token using the creds
- use the access token as session-id while subscribing to platform events for guest users.
- don't forget to remove the data access except for platform events.